# select by max value of another column

Tags: sql, t-sql

For example I have a table with price changes.

```
TABLE
(
ID INT,
ProductID INT,
ChangeDate DATE,
PriceOld MONEY,
PriceNew MONEY
)
```

I need select the actual prices for each product, i.e. select PriceNew where ChangeDate is max for each product

Comment: See analytical functions `rank` or `last_value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT ProductID,PriceNew 
FROM
( 
     SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY ChangeDate DESC) RN FROM Table1
) X 
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

> select PriceNew where ChangeDate is max for each product

I would phrase this using a correlated subquery for filtering. This seems to me like the simplest way to translate your requirement, and generally offers good performance compared to other methods (notably, window functions or self-join).

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where ChangeDate = (
    select max(t1.ChangeDate)
    from mytable t1
    where t1.ProductID = t.ProductID
);
```

For performance, you want an index on `(ProductID, ChangeDate)`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple method uses filtering in the `where` clause:

```
select t.productid, t.pricenew
from t
where t.changedate = (select max(t2.changedate)
                      from t t2
                      where t2.productid = t.productid
                     );
```

With an index on `(productid, changedate)`, this often has better performance than other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Analytic Window functions are your best bet -- see Vignesh Kumar A's answer which I upvoted.

If your SQL flavor does not have `ROW_NUMBER()` or `RANK()` you can accomplish the same thing with the following joins.

```
-- this can be problematic if there's multiple prices for the same max ChangeDate 
SELECT
    a.ID
    , a.ProductID
    , a.ChangeDate
    , a.PriceOld
    , a.PriceNew
FROM table a 
    JOIN (SELECT ProductID, max(ChangeDate) max_ChangeDate
            FROM TABLE
            GROUP BY ProductID) b
        ON b.ProductID = a.ProductID
        AND b.max_ChangeDate = a.ChangeDate

-- if IDs are monotonically increasing with time, you can exploit the following. This is better than directly using ChangeDate -- no collisions.        
SELECT
    a.ID
    , a.ProductID
    , a.ChangeDate
    , a.PriceOld
    , a.PriceNew
FROM table a 
    JOIN (SELECT ProductID, max(ID) max_ID
            FROM TABLE
            GROUP BY ProductID) b
        ON b.ProductID = a.ProductID
        AND b.max_ID = a.ID
```